# How to increase the width to the Omega sub-theme more than 950 usable pixels

Tags: 7, theming

I have created a new sub-theme of the Omega theme (version 7.x-2.1) in Drupal 7.

But I want to use 970 usable pixels instead of 950 pixels as the sub-theme offers in "Default container width".

How can I do this? Shall I change the 960.css file from *themes/omega/omega/css/960.css* or shall I overwrite the 960.css file form my sub-theme? What you suggest?

Comment: avoid hacking themes (or Core) when you don't have to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be not to touch to the original theme and create a new one where you can override without touching anything to the original.

Now, I can't help any more, I never used that theme and Drupal 7 yet.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have followed the advice of @Polzme and @Chaulky and I have created my own sub-theme and I modified there the style.

As for my specific requirement this was:

```
.container-12, .container-16, .container-24, .container-32 {
    width: 970px;
}

.container-32 .grid-1, .container-32 .grid-2, .container-32 .grid-3, .container-32 .grid-4, .container-32 .grid-5, .container-32 .grid-6, .container-32 .grid-7, .container-32 .grid-8, .container-32 .grid-9, .container-32 .grid-10, .container-32 .grid-11, .container-32 .grid-12, .container-32 .grid-13, .container-32 .grid-14, .container-32 .grid-15, .container-32 .grid-16, .container-32 .grid-17, .container-32 .grid-18, .container-32 .grid-19, .container-32 .grid-20, .container-32 .grid-21, .container-32 .grid-22, .container-32 .grid-23, .container-32 .grid-24, .container-32 .grid-25, .container-32 .grid-26, .container-32 .grid-27, .container-32 .grid-28, .container-32 .grid-29, .container-32 .grid-30, .container-32 .grid-31, .container-32 .grid-32 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```